# What to create pdf in react

Tags: node.js, pdf, reactjs

I am working on a (reactjs + webpack + nodejs + express) application and i have to create pdf of a page.

I try the following npm packages for that:

**urltopdf**
This npm package create the pdf of the website,that i pass it as param but when ever i pass the url of reactjs application, i download the blank pdf.
Need your favor inorder to complete this.

```
var myurlpdf = require("myurltopdf");
myurlpdf.myurltopdf("http://mind2minds.com", {fileName:"...../filename.pdf"}, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log("file created successfully");
  }
});
```

I also try the 
**pdfkit**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A React page isn't static, it's generated through JavaScript. I imagine that your HTML document is likely empty, save for the required tags, and an entry div where your React content goes. When you request the page, you are getting a blank page, and this will stay that way unless the JavaScript is run against the page. I don't have a solution, but I don't have enough reputation to put this as a comment.

There may be libraries which can handle this in Node.js, but I'm not sure. This was actually an issue with early search engines.